# Can different OPA apps share Databases?

Tags: opa

I'm just investigating OPA and trying to make the leap from a traditional LAMP background, so here's my first of many newbie questions:

Can I have two OPA apps sharing the same database, say one which writes into a database and another that reads from it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. A simple but complete example:

[db.opa]

```
database ./counter
db /counter : int
Counter = {{
  read() = /counter
  inc() = /counter <- read() + 1
}}
```

[db_read.opa]

```
server = one_page_server("Counter app", -> <>Counter value: {Counter.read()}</>)
```

[db_write.opa]

```
_ = Scheduler.timer(1000, -> Counter.inc())
```

Compile with:

```
 opa db_read.opa db.opa -o db_read.exe
 opa db_write.opa db.opa -o db_write.exe
```

Run the database server for database `counter` on port `5001`:

```
 opa-db-server -b 127.0.0.1:5001 --db-local counter
```

Run the applications, connecting to this database:

```
 ./db_read.exe --db-remote 127.0.0.1:5001
 ./db_write.exe --db-remote 127.0.0.1:5001
```

The `db_write` app updates the counter every second. You can see that with the `db_read` app by visiting `localhost:8080` (and refreshing the page).

Hope the Opa-DB experts will correct me if I got something wrong.

Comment: Thanks akoprowski, I'll try it later but it certainly looks like the key is using `opa-db-server -b 127.0.0.1:5001 --db-local counter`

Comment: Yep, just tried it and it worked. Got a few warnings about "Can't set node properties on client" but the concept worked fine. Thanks!